# Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

**Context :** I have an App with a form where you can select a muscle, and a number of exercices to do for this selected muscle.
The idea is to add any muscle you want with its number of exercices in the form.

`listOfMuscles` is just an Array with all existing muscles to work.

**What I want to do :** When I click on Add button, I want to create a new div (same as in `displayMuscleInProgram()` to let the user add a new muscle to his program.

**The problem :** With this code, I get an error saying : `Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'.`

**My questions :** Why is this error popping ? Is there a way with React to create DOM element. If yes, can you give me an example ?

I write here my entire page :

```
import { Formik, Form, Field } from "formik";
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { getAllMuscles, numberOfExercices } from "../helpers/dataModuler";
import { setInLocalStorage } from "../helpers/localStorageHandler";

const listOfMuscles = getAllMuscles();

export const ProgramForm: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  const listOfMuscles = getAllMuscles();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const initialValues = {
    numberOfExercices: 0,
    muscle: listOfMuscles[0]
  };

  const handleSubmit = (values: {}) => {
    setInLocalStorage("program", values);

    navigate("/programme");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        onSubmit={(values) => handleSubmit(values)}
      >
        <Form>
          <div id="container">
            <DisplayMuscleInProgram />
          </div>

          <button
            onClick={addMuscleToProgram}
            type="button"
            className="rounded-md border"
          >
            Add
          </button>

          <div className="text-center">
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="mt-8 rounded-lg bg-primary p-2 text-white"
            >
              Let's gooooo 
            </button>
          </div>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    </>
  );
};

export const DisplayMuscleInProgram: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="my-4 grid grid-cols-5 justify-between gap-5">
        <Field
          as="select"
          className="col-span-3 rounded-lg bg-lightGray p-3"
          name="muscle"
        >
          {listOfMuscles.map((muscle) => (
            <option key={muscle}>{muscle}</option>
          ))}
        </Field>
        <Field
          as="select"
          className="col-span-2 rounded-lg bg-lightGray p-3"
          name="numberOfExercices"
        >
          {numberOfExercices(10)}
        </Field>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const addMuscleToProgram = () => {
  const container = document.getElementById("container");

  if (container) container.appendChild(<DisplayMuscleInProgram />);
};
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible codesandbox link? What is `numberOfExercices`?

Comment: I can't provide an example :/ numberOfExercices is a function that returns a select with 10 options from 0 to 9

Comment: But I can provide my gitHub repository ?

Comment: I see you have changed your question. But about your original question: Does `numberOfExercices` returns a React element? If so when you execute `numberOfExercices(10).forEach((number) => {}`, `number` is an `Element` which you cannot assign it to `option.value`.

Comment: If your repository is public you can share it. Otherwise you can create a minimal reproducible generic code only of this part of your code, which does not contain any sensitive data in a codesandbox.

Comment: @c0m1t I saw online thet using JS to create HTML elements is not a good practice in React so yes, I changed my code. Now it works with Bernhard answer, but All my inputs changes when I change one. Do you know how I can make this unique ?
Thank you for your time btw

Comment: As I mentioned before, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just trying to give another approach.
Add a new state to hold the number of the muscle program

```
const [muscleProgram, setMuscleProgram] = useState(1)
```

and then add the component based on the number of the program.

```
<div id="container">
    {[...Array(muscleProgram)].map((n, i) =>
        <DisplayMuscleInProgram />
    )}
</div>

<button
    onClick={() => setMuscleProgram(muscleProgram+1)}
    type="button"
    className="rounded-md border">
    Add
</button>
```

Comment: Oh yes it works !! Now there is just a last "problem", one change on one input change all inputs. I should pass a unique key ?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure but you can try use the index (or unique id if you have) as the key.

Comment: If it's still not working, append the key to the `Field` name props like this `name="muscle-${key}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Parse number variable to string as document.createElement("option") taking value as string instead of Element type

Comment: I did it, but React does not add to DOM :/